# Could not found onClick method in MainActivity whereas it's implemented

Tags: android, animation, onclick

I have a `ImageView` in my android app and I want to make an animation whan I click on it.

Here is my XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/card_image_view"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onCardClicked"
    android:src="@drawable/card" />
```

and here is my java code :

```
package com.example.androidpart;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.v("hello", "Hello coucou!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    void onCardClicked(View view) {
        Log.v("oh!", "I clicked!");
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_image_view);
        // Using hardware layer
        view.animate().translationX(400); 
    }

}
```

The problem is that the application stops when I run it, and in the logcat it says that no method onCardClicked could be found in `MainActivity.java`, whereas it's here...

Can someone explain where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the onCardClicked to public

```
   public void onCardClicked(View view) {
    Log.v("oh!", "I clicked!");
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_image_view);
    // Using hardware layer
    view.animate().translationX(400); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

method must be public

```
public void onCardClicked(View view) {
    Log.v("oh!", "I clicked!");
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_image_view);
    // Using hardware layer
    view.animate().translationX(400); 
}
```

as documentation in [Developer.android Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

> In order for this [click event] to work, the method must be `public` and accept a `View` as its only parameter

Answer (score 1):

the correct signature for View.onClick is

```
public void onClick(View view)
```

so the signature of your method has to be

```
 public void onCardClicked(View view)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may consider doing the listener manually in code like this:

```
ImageView img = (Button) findViewById(R.id.card_image_view);  
    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            Log.v("oh!", "I clicked!");
        }  
    });
```

this way may prevent more issues at runtime in the future